# c++ std for_each define the std function later

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to change this code:

```
std::for_each( container.begin(), container.end(), std::bind(&Class::method1, _1, param));
```

where the container has pointers to Class, to a version that you would only pass the param:

```
// create the functor here ( bind to method1 or method2, etc)
// ....
//
std::for_each( container.begin(), container.end(), functor(param) );
```

I can't use lambdas.

The container can be:

```
 std::list<Class*>
```

Comment: You have some other options, but std::for_each can't pass parameters like this.

Comment: @ChrisWard1000 doesn't need to be this way the passing..just to achieve the end result

Comment: You can use a variable of type `std::function` as the argument

Comment: @JorenHeit I can use only std::function and std::bind from c++11

Comment: @P0W don't see how this matters, but let's say integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct functor {
    int param;
    functor(int param): param(param) {}
    void operator()(Class* c) {
        c->method1(param);
    }
};
```

There you go. A functor class that you can use exactly as your example. No lambda, no bind to a method. Just pass the parameter to the constructor. You can pass a member function pointer to the constructor or expand this to a template to avoid writing one for each method.

Or if you simply wanted to choose the method first and bind the parameter later, you could do this:

```
// create the functor here ( bind to method1 or method2, etc)
std::function<void(Class*,decltype(param))> functor(&Class::method1); // "bind" the method
// ....
std::for_each( container.begin(), container.end(), std::bind(functor, _1, param) ); // bind the param
```

Note that I don't see any advantage to doing this instead of the first line of code in your question.

Comment: I want to avoid creating functor for each methodx, as I have many of them...wasn't clear enough, sorry.

Comment: @yandreiy you can of course expand that to a template so you don't need to write code for each method, but I'm not sure I know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As to why i need it:
I will have the  `functor` be a class member and initialized later, with different argument in different places. So it makes code cleaner and shorter.

Comment: @yandreiy ok, I think that should really have been part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You want something to make the functor.

This is the general functor you are going to want.

```
template< typename CLASS, typename CLASS_METHOD, typename PARAM_TYPE >
class Functor
{
    CLASS_METHOD m_method; // actually will be of type void(CLASS::*func)( PARAM_TYPE )

    PARAM_TYPE m_param;

 public:
    void operator()( CLASS * c ) const
    {
       (c->*m_method)( m_param );
    }
};

template typename< CLASS, CLASS_METHOD, PARAM_TYPE > 
Functor< CLASS, CLASS_METHOD, PARAM_TYPE > 
functor( CLASS_METHOD method, PARAM_TYPE param )
{
      return Functor< CLASS, CLASS_METHOD, PARAM_TYPE >( method, param );
}

std::for_each
  ( 
    container.begin(), container.end(), 
    functor< Class >( &Class::method1, param );
  );
```

We can make it non-template if you prefer.

```
class Functor
{
     typedef void (Class::*func_type )(int);

     func_type m_method; // assuming that's the param type
     int m_param;

public:
     Functor( func_type method, int param )
         : m_method( method ), m_param( param )
     {
     }

     void operator()( Class * c ) const
     {
        (c->*m_method)(param);
     }
};

std::for_each( container.begin, container.end(), Functor( &Class::method1, param ) );
```

Now to "only" specify the param, you write functions for each "method" thus:

```
Functor method1Functor( int param )
{
      return Functor( &Class::method1, param );
}

Functor method2Functor( int param )
{
    return Functor( &Class::method2, param );
}
```

In your code now:

```
std::for_each( container.begin(), container.end(), method1Functor( param ) );
```

You could also write these function methods to do a `bind` and return a `std::function`.